# Assign icon to all forms in a powershell multiform gui with ps2exe

Tags: .net, powershell, winforms, compilation

I'm making a Winforms Application in Powershell that has 3 different forms and want to compile it into an .exe with ps2exe. I've used `-iconFile` for the icon but I'm running into a problem that only the 1st form uses the icon. The 2nd form opens once you press a button in the 1st form but it's using the standard .net winforms icon instead of the icon specified with ps2exe.

Is there any way I can assign the icon to all forms with ps2exe or a different tool? Maybe even in the script itself?

Comment: The problem is probably that `ps2exe` unpacks the PowerShell in a different location than you expect, see: [Random number generator not working after converting to Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73364877/1701026). Why do you want to use `ps2exe`? if it is to have a single file solution, you might also embed you icons as code64 in your PowerShell script similar to e.g.: [Converting JPG to base64 and back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55969034/1701026).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you might just embed your icons in the PowerShell script as follows:

- Load your icon as byte stream:

```
$Icon = Get-Content .\favicon.ico -AsByteStream
```

Or, (as for this example,) I am using the (fav)icon from this **StackOverflow** site:

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196
$Icon = $Response.Content
```

- Convert your icon to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String($Icon)
```

> Note that there also several online `base64` convertors as: https://www.base64decode.org/

- Copy the results (`[Convert]::ToBase64String($Icon) | Clip`) and paste it into your script where you assign it to a variable (e.g. `$Base64`)
- Convert your icon back from `Base64`
- Assign the icon to your form

```
$Base64 = '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'
$Form = [Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
$Form.Icon = [Drawing.Icon][IO.MemoryStream][Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

**Result:**

[image]